# Send Data from multiple threads to a single thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm coding a Java socket server that connects to Arduino which in turn send and receive data. As shown by the Java socket documentation I've set up the server to open a new thread for every connection.

My question is, how will I be able to send the data from the socket threads to my main thread? The socket will be constantly open, so the data has to be sent while the thread is running.
     Any suggestion?

Update: the goal of the server is to send commands to an Arduino (ie. Turn ligh on or off) and receive data from sensors, therefore I need a way to obtain that data from the sensors which are connected to individual threads and to send them into a single one.

Comment: I would recommend including some of the things you have tried already - as opposed to simply looking for a solution. Also as far as your question goes - there is a number of tutorials online for exactly what you are looking for. I'll see if I can quickly find one for you.

Comment: Needs some clarification. I did not get what is client and what is server.

Comment: What data needs to be shared (sent) to the main thread?  The socket threads send the data to the socket it owns, so it does not need to send the data to the main thread in order to send it to the client.

Comment: I'm not trying to send data to the clients, I'm trying to move all the received data from each socket threads into one.

Comment: Have you thought about Spring Messaging / Integration using WebSocket and STOMP? Arduino client hasn't to be necessarily a Java app, just needs to follow the STOMP protocol.

Comment: There's really no such thing as "sending data to main thread". Threads share memory, so any data in memory can be read by any thread. The shape of solution depends on what you want to do with the data. You could as well talk about "sending data from object to object". What would that mean?

Comment: servers don't connect to clients. Communication goes the other way around.

Comment: I realize that, that's why the clients have to remain connected.

Comment: Something's missing from your description.  What's the use of receiving data from sensors if you aren't going to _do_ something with it?  What are you going to do? and why does it have to be done in a single thread?  Anyway, assuming you have a good reason, why not use a _blocking queue_?  The sensor threads can receive data from the sensor, and _produce_ messages that they stuff in the queue.  The main thread can _consume_ message from the queue and do whatever with them.

Comment: @fdreger, you are thinking at the wrong level of abstraction.  Yea, threads all share the same address space, but at a higher level, they use structures in the shared memory as a means to communicate with each other.

Comment: @james large, I'm going to display the data as a web page and you are right, blocking queue is the way to go

Comment: @jameslarge I don't think I am "thinking at the wrong level of abstraction". I was just stating that the question was too abstract to be answered (there is no "sending data" as such, we need more details), and your comment is basically repeating what I said (-> asking for more data). Btw: if I understand the requirements (sketchy as they are), blocking queue is far from being a good choice.

Comment: @fdreger, In programs I write, threads send data (messages) to each  other.  You may say that all they're _really_ doing is writing to shared memory, but that is because you are describing it at a low level of abstraction--close to the hardware.  You said, "You could just as well talk about sending data from object to object [but] what would that mean?"  It would mean whatever the designer of the program _wants_ it to mean.  _Really_, the computer is nothing but a machine that moves bits around.  Numbers, text, and pictures are arbitrary meanings that we _assign_ to those bits.

Comment: @fdreger, we typically assign _layers_ of meaning (levels of abstraction), one on top of another until we have enormously complex systems, like the so-called "cognitive" systems that I work with that extract "meaning" from text.  But, if you focus on what's _really_ happening (i.e., at the physical level), all you've got to talk about is a few billion transistors, turning on and off according to simple rules.

Comment: @jameslarge: you are thinking at the wrong level of abstraction - the transistors are just mental constructs used to reason about billions of elementary particles. But going back to my answer - Java (the language) has no abstractions for "sending data between threads". The question was about Java. So my level of abstraction was quite adequate.

Comment: @jameslarge more seriously - you can introduce handy abstractions like "task" and "worker" or "message" - but all of them are above the abstraction level set by Java. As you said yourself:  "It would mean whatever the designer of the program wants it to mean.", which is a nice way of saying that in Java - they are quite meaningless. In this sepcific case I believe that a simple volatile field is the best solution to the problem presented by the question - and while setting a field could be described as "sending a message", I don't think such description would be meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing data among threads is always tricky. There is no "correct" answer, it all depends on your use case. I suppose you are not searching for the highest performance, but for easiness of use, right?

For that case, I would recommend looking at synchronized collections, maps, lists or queues perhaps. One class, which seems like a good fit for you, is *ConcurrentLinkedQueue*.

You can also create synchronized proxies for all usual collections using the factory methods in Collections class:

```
    Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

You do not have to synchronize access to them.

Another option, which might be an overkill, is using database. There are some in-memory databases, like H2.

In any case, I suggest you to lower the amount of shared information to the lowest possible level. For example, you can keep the "raw" data separate per thread (e.g. in *ThreadLocal* variables) and then just synchronize during aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the right idea - you need a thread to run the connection to the external device and you need a main thread to run your application.

How do you share data between these threads: This isn't in general a problem - different threads can write to the same memory; within the same application threads share memory space.

What you probably want to avoid is the two thread concurrently changing or reading the data - java provides a very useful keyword - synchronized - to handle this sort of situation which is straight forward to use and provides the kind of guarantees you need. [This is a bit technical](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) but discusses the concurrency features.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial you might be able to get some more information on. Please note, a quick google search will bring up lots of answers to your question.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html

In answer to your question, you can send the information from one thread to another by using a number of options - I would recommend if it is a simple setup, just use static variables/methods to pass the information.

Also as reference, for large scale programs, it is not recommended to start a thread for every connection. It works fine on smaller scale (e.g. a few number of clients), but scales poorly.

Comment: Thanks for the link but the threads don't have a specific task that can be run and then closed, my goal would be to keep them always connected since data also has to be sent to them.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web application and you are just going to show the current readout of any of the sensors, then blocking queue is a *huge* overkill and will cause more problems than it solves. Just use a volatile static field of the required type. The field itself can be static, or it could reside in a singleton object, or it could be part of a context passed to the worker.

in the `SharedState` class:

```
static volatile float temperature;
```

in the thread:

```
SharedState.temperature = 13.2f;
```

In the web interface (assuming jsp):

```
<%= SharedState.temperature %>
```

btw: if you want to access last 10 readouts, then it's equally easy: just store an array with last 10 readouts instead of a single value (just don't modifiy what's inside the array, replace the whole array instead - otherwise synchronization issues might occur).